# Service Cloud Console Page Dispatcher not working

Tags: service-cloud-console, console, service

Use case:
We redirect our service cloud agents to a custom case time-tracking object after they create a case comment or send an email. This works and has been working. We deployed the console to our users and this is now primary way for them to update cases. The redirect does not work within the console.

Workaround:
They are manually going to the custom object and creating the time entry instead of being taken to object automatically

Trying to find another approach / architecture for this - any advice?